# How to split multiple rows across one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My data set:

```
|-------|------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|OrderNo| Line |Customer | Desc  |Unit   |Price  | Amount|
|-------|------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|S123456|10    | John    | shirt | 1.00  | 19.99 | 0.00  |
|-------|------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|S123456|02    | John    | pants | 0.00  | 40.00 | 40.00 |
|-------|------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|S123777|01    | Jane    | misc  | 0.00  | 0.00  | 10.00 |
|-------|------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|S123777|02    | Jane    | pants | 0.00  | 40.00 | 40.00 |
```

Results trying to achieve:

```
|-------|---------|------|------|------|-------|--------|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|OrderNo|Customer |Line1 |Desc1 |Unit1 |Price1 |Amount1 |Line2 |Desc 2|Unit2 |Price2 |Amount 2|
|-------|---------|------|------|------|-------|--------|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|S123456|John     |10    |shirt |1.00  |19.99  |0.00    |02    |pants |0.00  |40.00  |40.00   |
|-------|---------|------|------|------|-------|--------|------|------|------|-------|--------|
|S123777|Jane     |01    | misc |0.00  |0.00   |10.00   |02    |pants |0.00  |40.00  |40.00   |
|-------|---------|------|------|------|-------|--------|------|------|------|-------|--------|
```

**ABOUT THE DATA**

*Server:* MSSQL Server 2012

*Data Type:*

[OrderNo] nvarchar NOT NULL

, [Line] [int] NOT NULL

, [Customer] nvarchar NOT NULL

, [Desc] nvarchar NOT NULL

, [Unit] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL

, [Price] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL

, [Amount] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL

I want to see one row per OrderNo. Trying to view all lines within an order per row.

Unfortunately the line number isn't reliable in it's number for the data I need to pull (sometimes line 03 is used for a comment and not an actual item), so I'm unclear how to fetch the second row to split into the desired result set.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Try using a join of two result sets:  GROUP BY MIN(Line) ; GROUP BY MAX(Line) :: JOIN ON OrderNo

Comment: So if one order has 22 items in it, you want 112 columns in the output for all rows, even if all other orders only have 2 items? That could get ugly really quickly.

Comment: Our lines don't typically exceed more than 5 lines. Most common is 2-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to go Dynamic.  Just replace YourTable with your actual table name.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 
Stuff((Select ','+QuoteName(concat('Line'  ,RN)) 
             +','+QuoteName(concat('Desc'  ,RN)) 
             +','+QuoteName(concat('Unit'  ,RN)) 
             +','+QuoteName(concat('Price' ,RN)) 
             +','+QuoteName(concat('Amount',RN)) 
        From (Select Distinct RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By OrderNo Order By Line) From YourTable) A  
        Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Select @SQL = '
Select [OrderNo],[Customer],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select A.OrderNo
              ,A.Customer
              ,B.*
         From (Select *,RN = cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By OrderNo Order By Line) as varchar(25)) From YourTable) A
         Cross Apply (Values (''Line''  +A.RN,cast(A.[Line] as varchar(250)))
                            ,(''Desc''  +A.RN,cast(A.[Desc] as varchar(250))) 
                            ,(''Unit''  +A.RN,Format(A.[Unit]  ,''#,##0.00'')) 
                            ,(''Price'' +A.RN,Format(A.[Price] ,''#,##0.00'')) 
                            ,(''Amount''+A.RN,Format(A.[Amount],''#,##0.00'')) 
                      ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

---

**If it helps with the visualization**, the generated SQL looks like this:

```
Select [OrderNo],[Customer],[Line1],[Desc1],[Unit1],[Price1],[Amount1],[Line2],[Desc2],[Unit2],[Price2],[Amount2]
From (
        Select A.OrderNo
              ,A.Customer
              ,B.*
         From (Select *,RN = cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By OrderNo Order By Line) as varchar(25)) From YourTable) A
         Cross Apply (Values ('Line'  +A.RN,cast(A.[Line] as varchar(250)))
                            ,('Desc'  +A.RN,cast(A.[Desc] as varchar(250))) 
                            ,('Unit'  +A.RN,Format(A.[Unit]  ,'#,##0.00')) 
                            ,('Price' +A.RN,Format(A.[Price] ,'#,##0.00')) 
                            ,('Amount'+A.RN,Format(A.[Amount],'#,##0.00')) 
                      ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ([Line1],[Desc1],[Unit1],[Price1],[Amount1],[Line2],[Desc2],[Unit2],[Price2],[Amount2]) ) p
```

And the sub-query produces this

[image]

Comment: I receive an error on the A subquery "Conversion failed when converting the nchar value '' to data type int." it looks like it is on the Desc field. Not sure what to do? I assume Casting as varchar somewhere, but within the Values section didn't work for me. Thanks! Edit clarification: im testing the "visualization" section

Comment: @CoffeeCoder what are the data type of the sample data provided.

Comment: @CoffeeCoder See update I added a case to varchar in the sub-query for Line and Desc

Comment: I edited my question to include the data types. The varchar fixed it, I had a typo and didn't place the parans in the right place. Thank you John!